# Laravel RAW query to add multiple columns float value

Tags: php, laravel, phpmyadmin

I'm storing value into database like 9:30 and 1 (my datatype is float in database for this column), when i'm retrieving i cant able to add two numbers , it is printing like 10 but it must be in 10:30 , i'm using laravel to add these two column

```
     $get=DB::table('table_name')->select(DB::raw('sum(hours) AS hours'))
                                 ->get();
```

can anyone please solve my issue ??

Comment: First thing to do, is to actually maintain some kind of format, if `9:30` exists, the 1 has to be `1:00` atleast so that you maintain the `hh:mm` format. Then use the `DATEDIFF(T1, '00:00')` and `SUM` them

Comment: Yeah it is in like 9:30 and 1:00 , how can i sum it my datatype is varchar

Comment: `9:30` is not a valid float value (is it?) Chances are you tried to put `9:30` in a float column and ended up having a `9.0` in there

Comment: yeah yes , i'm storing like 9.30 and 1.00

Comment: if that's the case then the database should be returning `10.3` as a result (you can verify by doing a raw query on it). You might be accidentally trimming or rounding it somewhere further down the code.

Comment: Check out http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d87ca9/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best thing to do is to change the datatype from float to integer. Generally in most programming and database level, float value is problematic and could also lead to precision issues/problems.

So my proposal is:

- Store the time in minutes (or the least unit based on your situation)
- Retrieve it, and divide it by 60 then you have the right value without employing hacky and unstable ways to resolve it.

I hope this is useful.

Comment: Yeah i think it is a easy way, Thanx

Comment: Glad it is useful. Just for you to note that after you divide minutes by 60 you will have a normal float value e.g. 9.50 which is the same as 9 hours and 30 minute. I hope you understand what I mean so you don't feel worried, you can use php datetime or Carbon to format the output as you want.

Answer (score 2):

float is for numbers with comma `,` . What you want to save a clock time with `:`.

So you could convert your time to float before storing it to the database, `10:30 -> 10.5` and then sum it up like

```
$get=DB::table('table_name')->select(DB::raw('sum(hours) AS hours'))
                             ->first();
$hours = str_replace('.', ':', $get->hours);
```

This solution isn't the beast because there are better approaches to deal with dates by saving them as a date object and not as a float one.

Another approach is to use `smalldatetime` instead of float to save the value. Then you save times and not numbers with that you can work.

Comment: The decimal separator can be either `,` or `.` depending on the locale (I think europe prefers `,` and US prefers `.` ) The point is no one uses `:` as a decimal separator.

Comment: table('table')->select(DB::raw('sum(hours) AS hours'))   can u please change this query for adding ??? :(

Comment: updated my answer. This should work if you store them like `9.3`

Comment: please print use your hours table so we can see what type of input you have

Comment: my input is 9.30 in one column and another column is 1.00 it is adding and printing number in 10.30 in need it like 10:30...

Comment: You can format the output with a simple replace function after you got it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do so after retrieving your data from db

```
$n1 = '9:30';
$timestamp = strtotime($n1);
echo date('H:i',strtotime('+1 hour',$timestamp));
```

Comment: after retriving it is not like 9:30 it is like 9.30

Comment: you have to change the way storing your value in db. Why not using Date data type instead? The way you are doing things is not good practice, you'll find problems when manipulating data.

Comment: even if your " my input is 9.30 in one column and another column is 1.00 it is adding and printing number in 10.30 in need it like 10:30" then simply remove dot with colon that will do the job.